# Proper formatting of Excel sheets to avoid errors in SQL querying?

Tags: sql, excel, formatting, integer, varchar

1. What do you avoid when creating and filling out a Excel spreadsheet of data for a SQL database (certain formats, characters, character length issues?)

2.Does it matter how dates are formatted?

3. VARCHAR or INTEGER errors you've seen?
4. Finally, what SQL or Python queries did you use to address errors you found that you might have shared for questions 1-3?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be, if you can import Database-EDI (e.g. Oracle SQL Developer) a TXT- or CSV-Excel-Export into our Database.
→ Depending on the database, different requirements must be observed.

The main focus is on the correct formatting with regard to the country settings (Excel & database):

- Excel-Format-Date YYYY-M-DD HH24:MM / Databe-Timestamp YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS.FFFF
  → That would not work

In addition, make sure that Excel does not cut any numbers:

- Excel-Format-Long-Number 89632150000  (orignal 896321512345  )
  → Excel automatically shortens the number in the standard settings.

The length of a text must not exceed the specified maximum length in the assigned column of the type (VARCHAR).

I think these would be the main points to look out for.